# My custom table not being created on wordpress plugin activation

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create my own custom table in wordpress database on plugin activation ..This is my code for that ..

```
function __construct()
    {
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,array(&$this, 'activate'));


    function activate()
    {

    global $wpdb;
    echo "<div class='updated'>Test Plugin Notice</div>";

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "dive";

    $installed_ver = get_option( "divebook_db_table_dive_version" );
     //Check if the table already exists and if the table is up to date, if not create it
    if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_name
            ||  $installed_ver != $divebook_db_table_dive_version ) {
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . " (
              id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              date bigint(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
              site tinytext NOT NULL,
              description text NOT NULL,
              max_depth mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
              time mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
              UNIQUE KEY id (id)
            );";

        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
        dbDelta($sql);
        update_option( "divebook_db_table_dive_version", $divebook_db_table_dive_version );

}
    //Add database table versions to options
    add_option("divebook_db_table_dive_version", $divebook_db_table_dive_version);

   }
}
```

I m checking my database .No new table has been created ..Plz look into it ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because any WP activation/deactivation hook needs to be run from inside the plugin main file, not from a file you include in the main file.
So, try to run the activation hook from your plugin-name.php file and it will work.

L.E:
also, i don't see $divebook_db_table_dive_version being defined. Another thing, dbDelta caused problems for me in the past, try with $wpdb->query() to run the create table query.

Comment: i assume `function __construct()` is part of a class and you instantiate that class using the `new` operator, right?

Comment: also, i don't see `$divebook_db_table_dive_version` being defined. Another thing, dbDelta caused problems for me in the past, try with `$wpdb->query()` to run the create table query.

Comment: yeah this function is part of class and that is instantiated on cond (if!is_admin)

Comment: dbdelta is working for me onclick but not here on plugin activation..and also i have defined ..sorry but forgot to mention here.. i have nw tried with $wpdb->query($sql); also but no results

Comment: see my last comment and also add here your entire file contents. Also, if you put an exit statement right before your $sql var, does the script exits? i mean, does it reaches the piece of code where you need to run the sql? Another advice, try to create a simple function and register it as an activation hook instead of having it in a class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28781/discussion-between-user1145009-and-twisted1919)

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of incorrect SQL query
just check the documentation here
https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)